# How to use Chalk Terminal string styling done right

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, npm

I've had no luck in seeing any results appear in my iTerm2 while trying to use chalk which is a terminal string styling package. I followed all the steps in installing the package but I'm not seeing any colored string result appear when I run a basic `console.log("hello");` in my `chalk.js` file.

Here is what I am doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var chalk = require('chalk');
chalk.blue('Hello world!');
console.log("hello");
```

Then in iTerm2 I run `node chalk.js` and I see no colored strings just plane old boring grey..

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk

Comment: It should "just" work, since Iterm2 sets `TERM` to `xterm` by default, and that is what chalk checks for - see source https://github.com/sindresorhus/supports-color/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @ThomasDickey thax for your imput. Can you tell me exactly how you get it run "your set up" for chalk?

Comment: I was reading the source code to help explain it -- can setup to explore that a little...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chalk functions return a string with the appropriate ANSI escape codes.

You need to console log the result of chalk calls.

```
console.log(chalk.blue("Hello, world!"));
```

If you still don't see any color, try running with the command line argument `--colors`. If that still doesn't work, set an environment variable `FORCE_COLOR=1`.

If it *still* doesn't work, you're welcome to [file a bug report](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues)!

Comment: Works like a charm! `console.log(chalk.yellow('hello'));` Finally got around to testing it out.